# Fire AJAX jQuery if scroll reach to each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want make `ajax` fire if scroll reach to each div element.

- Item div 1
- Item div 2 (fire ajax if scroll to this element)
- Item div 3 (fire ajax again if scroll to this element)
- Item .....N

I use this code, but only fire if scroll to end.

```js
$( window ).scroll( function() {
     if( $( window ).scrollTop() == $( document ).height() - $( window ).height() ) {
      alert('Fire!');
     }
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: If you are going to fire an ajax call on scroll make sure you put in something to make it only fire once otherwise you will end up with hundreds of requests each time you scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.offset().top` instead of heights.

To check all sections you can use `$.each()`. Since I am guessing you only want to fire the event once, you will need a variable to remember all sections, that already fired.

```js
let firedEvents = [];

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("div.section").each(function() {
    if (!firedEvents.includes(this) && $(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top) {
      firedEvents.push(this);
      alert("fire " + $(this).data("nr"));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" data-nr="0" style="background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="section" data-nr="1" style="background-color: green;"></div>
<div class="section" data-nr="2" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
<div class="section" data-nr="3" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: What the function `let firedEvents = []`

Comment: that is defining a variable named `firedEvents` and initializes it as an empty array?

Comment: Can i use 'var' instead 'let'? What different 'var' and 'let'?

Comment: yes you can. ES6 introduced `let` and `const` and they help prevent unexpected results. If you are interested in that, [this article looks good.](https://hackernoon.com/js-var-let-or-const-67e51dbb716f)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var scrolled = $( window ).scrollTop();

    $('div:not(.fired)').each(function () {
        var position_of_div = $(this).offset();
        if (scrolled > position_of_div.top) {
            $(this).addClass('fired');
            alert('fire');
        }
    });
});
```

Save the scrolled pixels in an variable. On scroll get the position of each div. If the amount of pixels scrolled is greater than the offset of the div (related to the document) fire a AJAX call.

Comment: Note that this will potentially fire hundreds of AJAX calls per second when you are scrolling. Not only, because `$.scroll` is fired a lot, but also, because it will fire once for every div that it has scrolled past.

Comment: @SourceOverflow, exactly right. I try and it fire hundreds AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of writing a simple html that will fullfil your needs.
In my example scroll happens via button click; u can change it with your usecase; Hope this helps; here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/39z82axt/

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="divel">Element 1</div>
<div class="divel">Element 2</div>
<div class="divel">Element 3</div>
<div class="divel">Element 4</div>
<div class="divel">Element 5</div>
</div>
<button id="scrollButton">
Click to Scroll
</button>
```

css

```
 .divel {
  height:80px;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

js

```
let crossedFirstDiv = false, 
    crossedSecondDiv = false;

document.getElementById('scrollButton').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollTop += 10;   
   let scrollLocation = scrollPosition("wrapper");
   if (scrollLocation > 10 && scrollLocation <20 && crossedFirstDiv == false) {
   alert("crossing div 1");
   crossedFirstDiv = true;
   }
   else if (scrollLocation > 20 && scrollLocation <30 && crossedSecondDiv == false) {
   crossedSecondDiv = true;
   alert("crossing div 2");
   }   

   // and so on..
}

function scrollPosition(elementId) {
  let a = document.getElementById(elementId).scrollTop; 
   let b = document.getElementById(elementId).scrollHeight - document.getElementById(elementId).clientHeight;
   let c = a / b;
   return Math.floor(c * 100);
}
```